# Mybatis doesn't return all rows, return just 1 row

Tags: mybatis

here is my mybatis query

```
<select id="selectTotalStateList" resultMap="BaseResultMap" >
select 
  A.LOFFICE_NO
  ,(select SOFFICE_NAME from OFFICE where LOFFICE_NO = a.LOFFICE_NO) as OFFICE_NAME
  ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'00',1)),0) as AUTO0
  ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'01',1)),0) as AUTO1
  ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'02',1)),0) as AUTO2
  ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'03',1)),0) as AUTO3
  ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'04',1)),0) as AUTO4
  ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'05',1)),0) as AUTO5
  ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,1,1)),0) as AWS
  ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,2,1)),0) as TEXT
  from KNPSAWS.TBL_DISASTER_WARNING_CARD a
  group by ROLLUP(A.LOFFICE_NO)
  order by A.LOFFICE_NO
  </select>
```

and here is app log query

```
select A.LOFFICE_NO ,(select SOFFICE_NAME from OFFICE where LOFFICE_NO = a.LOFFICE_NO) as OFFICE_NAME 
,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'00',1)),0) as HTYPE ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'01',1)),0) 
as DETAILED_TYPE ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'02',1)),0) as TOTAL_TYPE ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'03',1)),0) 
as AUTO3 ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'04',1)),0) as SEA_LEVEL ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,'05',1)),0) 
as REGION_NAME ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,1,1)),0) as WIDTH ,nvl(count(DECODE(A.TOTAL_TYPE,2,1)),0) 
as LENGTH from KNPSAWS.TBL_DISASTER_WARNING_CARD a group by ROLLUP(A.LOFFICE_NO) order by A.LOFFICE_NO
```

these are perfectly same query what i expected.

it's real returning result on Sql Developer

```
4   AA  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
6   DD  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
        1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

but mybatis return only first row.

I've never experienced such like this before T.T

That resultmap is fine...cuz I've used this map without any problem.
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

interfaceMapper.java

```
public List<ClassName> selectTotalStateList();
```